# Why does this html border only have 3 sides?

Tags: html, css, border

Why does:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    #categorizer { border-style: solid; border-width: 10px; 
                   border-color: blue; padding: 50px }
    #children { color: green; background-color: yellow }
    #parents { color: blue; background-color: #ccc }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span id="categorizer">
      <span id="children">
        <span class="child">c11111</span>
        <span class="child">c22222</span>
        <span class="child">c33333</span>
        <span class="child">c44444</span>
        <span class="child">c55555</span>
      </span>
      <span id="parents">
        <span class="parent">pAAA</span>
        <span class="parent">pBBB</span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

only give me three border sides, i.e.

[image]

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't be using a `span`. A `div` would be more appropriate in this case, because these are not inline elements. And you shouldn't be using w3schools

Answer (score 4):

As implied by Cody Guldner in his comment, your `span`s are inline elements, not block elements. Because of this, padding doesn't change the text's vertical spacing; it just adds padding *around the text*, then the borders are added to the edge of the padding. It's this padding that's pushing the top blue border out of sight.

Answer (score 1):

You may also add display:block into categorizer

```
#categorizer { border-style: solid; border-width: 10px; 
               border-color: blue; padding:50px; display:block; }
```